# Drop Down Button Value is getting changed in every item of grid view flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, gridview, drop-down-menu

I'm creating an application which requires the user to select a value from the drop-down from every item of grid view. But when I select a value from a drop-down it changes value for other drop-down too.

```
GridView.builder(
        itemCount: 50,
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: 2, childAspectRatio: 1),
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return new Card(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                DropdownButton(
                  hint: _dropDownValue == null
                      ? Text('Dropdown')
                      : Text(
                          _dropDownValue,
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
                        ),
                  isExpanded: true,
                  iconSize: 30.0,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
                  items: ['One', 'Two', 'Three'].map(
                    (val) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                        value: val,
                        child: Text(val),
                      );
                    },
                  ).toList(),
                  onChanged: (val) {
                    setState(
                      () {
                        _dropDownValue = val;
                      },
                    );
                  },
                )
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
```

This is the code I'm using. 
[image: Problem I'm Facing]

Screenshot of Problem I'm Facing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you retrieve the value for every DropDown using `_dropDownValue`. In order to make it work, you have to store each selection for each Grid using a e.g. List or Map.

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {

  List<String> values = [
    "Grid 1 selection",
    "Grid 2 selection",
    "..."
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView.builder(
        itemCount: 50,
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: 2, childAspectRatio: 1),
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return new Card(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                DropdownButton(
                  hint: values[index] == null
                      ? Text('Dropdown')
                      : Text(
                          values[index],
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
                        ),
                  isExpanded: true,
                  iconSize: 30.0,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
                  items: ['One', 'Two', 'Three'].map(
                    (val) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                        value: val,
                        child: Text(val),
                      );
                    },
                  ).toList(),
                  onChanged: (val) {
                    setState(
                      () {
                        values[index] = val;
                      },
                    );
                  },
                )
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      );
  }
}
```